# Why I'm unable to use up/down arrows in my BIOS?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, boot, bios, hp-pavilion

My BIOS is loading and when I wanted to change anything, the up/down arrows aren't working. What might be the problem? I want to change boot options, but I'm unable to select the boot from CD option.

My BIOS version is f2.3. Do I need to upgrade it? I need my system for 2 more months continuously and I'm afraid if there might be some problem upgrading. But anyway, what might be the cause for this behavior?

For you info I have the pavilion dv6 series laptop, BIOS version: f.23 processer: Intel(R) core(TM) i3 CPU M 370 @ 2.40ghz 2.40GHZ 2.40 GHZ

Comment: Have you checked for any instructions at the bottom of the screen? Some BIOS screens are not intuitive and require you to press keys that are not obvious. Also, does the keyboard work OK in Windows etc?

Comment: Yeah, I checked, the down/up arrow keys are to select an option. Also the keyboard is working fine with windows and even left/right arrows are working fine in BIOS settings, but only problem is with up/down arrow!

Comment: For you info 

I have the pavilion dv6 series laptop, BIOS version: f.23

processer: Intel(R) core(TM) i3 CPU M 370 @ 2.40ghz 2.40GHZ 2.40 GHZ

Comment: Is it a USB Keyboard?

Comment: Is it a USB Keyboard? Try with a serial Keyboard.

Comment: I'm not using usb keyboard.

Comment: was the keyboard attached to the computer when it powered on? are you connecting the ps/2 keyboard to the right slot? (pink/purple one is for keyboard)

Comment: I'm using laptop. Not using external keyboard?!

Comment: @LorenzoVonMatterhorn

Comment: sorry for my failure @nexus . are you able somehow to connect an external keyboard?

Comment: I don't have an external keyboard rightnow!Do you think it's a keyboard fault?! I think the problem is with BIOS?! @LorenzoVonMatterhorn

Comment: Same problem with HP Pavilion 15 Notebook PC from 2014. left-right keys work with external keyboard

Answer (score 1):

Try Checking at the top or bottom for instructions . Some systems use + & - keys, while some use Page up & page down....
Also try changing your keyboard if its a usb one, try using a legacy Keyboard